# My java zybook's code isnt working for floating point formatting

Tags: java, floating-point, double

this is what my textbook says

[image: 1]

[this is my code]

```
package streams;

public class streams {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double myDouble = 12345.12345;
        System.out.printf("%10.10f ok %n", myDouble);
        System.out.printf("%-10.10f ok %n", myDouble);
        System.out.printf("%010.10f ok %n", myDouble);
    }
}
```

[this is my output]

```
12345.1230468750 ok 
12345.1230468750 ok 
12345.1230468750 ok
```

My question is, why are the numbers before the decimal point not formatted?

I expected that the first print would output:

```
 12345.1234500000 ok
```

second print:

12345.1234500000      ok

third one:

0000012345.1234500000 ok

Comment: I played around with the code and found out that the the numbers before the decimal only get formatted if im not crossing the limit on the other side of the decimal.

Comment: The first number refers to the entire size of the number, not the number of digits before the decimal place

Comment: The first entry is the minimum length of the string produced for the given object. The second number is format specific, it can be the digits after the dot or the total number of valid digits. // You might want to try to change the format specifier to `lf`, it looks like the double is converted first to single to conform to the given specifier `f`.